# uvicorn random error "Invalid HTTP request received"

Tags: python, multiprocessing, uvicorn, httpx

Using latest uvicorn[standard] 0.17.1. Tried `config(timeout_keep_alive=0, http='h11',...)` and the default (http='auto', which uses httptools). Using `uvloop`.

Running server in another process; calling it using `httpx`. Keep getting "Invalid HTTP request" (httptools and h11 both got issues, seemingly of similar nature). Appears random. Some times fail after a few more calls.

It works fine using `starlette` `TestClient` with the same data.

Just got some detailed error info (but note: this call with same client payload does not always fail):

```
[2022-02-02 19:22:37.128 US/Pacific; WARNING; uvicorn.error, handle_events, 139]  [Process-3:1]  Invalid HTTP request received.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 136, in handle_events
    event = self.conn.next_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 443, in next_event
    exc._reraise_as_remote_protocol_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/h11/_util.py", line 76, in _reraise_as_remote_protocol_error
    raise self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 425, in next_event
    event = self._extract_next_receive_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 367, in _extract_next_receive_event
    event = self._reader(self._receive_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/h11/_readers.py", line 72, in maybe_read_from_IDLE_client
    matches = validate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/h11/_util.py", line 88, in validate
    raise LocalProtocolError(msg)
h11._util.RemoteProtocolError: illegal request line: bytearray(b'{"top_k":null,"data":{"product_id":"4JQX8FA96PDF","product_attributes":{"":{"values":[{"value":"Womens Shirts"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"product_short_description":{"values":[{"value":"Gildan Pre-Shrunk Apparel 100% Cotton Jersey Fashion Fit: Missy contoured silhouette with side seam Double-needle stitched hems. Seamless double needle 1/2 collar Proudly designed / printed in the United States and we ship from beautiful California Wash Inside Out with Cold Water. Hand dry recommended.   Backed by JHI 100% Money Back Comfort Guarantee. We take great pride in our strong reputation for ethical business practices and the success of our customer care program. Commercial grade, durable high quality print professionally applied. A soft breathable secure fit wash after wash. All of our garment print production is done in our state-of-the-art production facility located in the U.S. This garment is designed and printed in USA with new age printing technology. Eco-friendly water-soluble ink-so it is safe for you and the environment. Each garment is handled separately in order for us to control the quality. Our garments are top quality, designed to give you maximum comfort and style. It features a comfortable and stylish design and is great for parties, casual get-togethers or everyday wear. This garment will be an everyday staple in your wardrobe. Super cute and super trendy, it\'s perfectly paired with your favorite jeans or leggings. You can pair it with shorts or pants for a relaxed and casual look.  This garment will be an everyday staple in your wardrobe. Super cute and super trendy, it\'s perfectly paired with your favorite jeans, leggings, shorts, pants, hats for a relaxed and casual look.  This item is available in a variety of colors and a range of sizes so you can find the ideal fit. Men\'s, Women\'s and Youth version available for most of our products. Fabric Care Instructions: Regular Cold Wash. Machine wash cold with like colors; inside out if decorated; non chlorine bleach when needed; tumble dry low; low iron excluding decoration.     Great for Christmas gifts, birthdays, holidays or just to treat yourself to a great graphic garment. We offer a large variety of graphic designs, colors and sizes for men, women and kids. Among our products: t-shirts, tank tops, long-sleeve tees, sweatshirts, fleece, hoodies and other activewear. "}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"features":{"values":[{"value":"Tear away label adds to the comfort eliminating scratchy irritation."}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"color":{"values":[{"value":"Black"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"color_category":{"values":[{"value":"Black"}],"properties":{"source":"MARKETPLACE_PARTNER"}},"autographed":{"values":[{"value":"N"}],"properties":{"source":"braavos"}},"clothing_size_group":{"values":[{"value":"Women"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"clothing_shoulder_style":{"values":[{"value":"Womens Shirts"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"age_group":{"values":[{"value":"Adult"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"fabric_care_instructions":{"values":[{"value":"Machine Wash Cold, Gentle Cycle"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"global_product_type":{"values":[{"value":"default","id":"-1"}],"properties":{"source":"braavos_classification"}},"pattern":{"values":[{"value":"Graphic Design"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"style_sleeve_length":{"values":[{"value":"Short Sleeve"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"material_name":{"values":[{"value":"Cotton"}],"properties":{"source":"attribute_extraction"}},"product_category":{"values":[{"value":"Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"}],"properties":{"source":"crowd:nextwealth"}},"product_name":{"values":[{"value":"Novelty T-Shirt DAE in Yellow  Womens Shirts"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"clothing_size":{"values":[{"value":"S"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"style_clothing_top":{"values":[{"value":"Womens Shirts"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"brand":{"values":[{"value":"J_H_I"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"style_sleeve":{"values":[{"value":"Short Sleeve"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"clothing_style":{"values":[{"value":"Womens Shirts"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"condition":{"values":[{"value":"New"}],"properties":{"source":"braavos"}},"actual_color":{"values":[{"value":"Black"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"product_type":{"values":[{"value":"T-Shirts","tag_source":"crowd:nextwealth","id":"t_shirts"}],"properties":{"source":"crowd:nextwealth"}},"product_pt_family":{"values":[{"value":"Upper-Body Garments"}],"properties":{"source":"crowd:nextwealth"}},"fit_clothing":{"values":[{"value":"Women\'s"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"gender":{"values":[{"value":"Female"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"country_of_origin_textiles":{"values":[{"value":"USA"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"shirt_neck_style":{"values":[{"value":"Womens Shirts"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"style_shirt":{"values":[{"value":"Womens Shirts"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"age_demographic":{"values":[{"value":"Women"}],"properties":{"source":"merchant_manual"}},"shirt_size":{"values":[{"value":"S"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"clothing_back_style":{"values":[{"value":"Womens Shirts"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"ironbank_category":{"values":[{"value":"Clothing"}],"properties":{"source":"mp"}},"apparel_category":{"values":[{"value":"Women"}],"properties":{"source":"braavos"}}},"assets":{"values":[{"properties":{"assetUrl":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/d4a5c7ff-4209-4296-89cb-d8af04b2ef98_1.62c8cf0295e81998bcba24929b587ed0.jpeg"}}]},"source_assets":{"values":[{"properties":{"assetUrl":"NOT FOUND"}}]}},"prefiltered":true}POST /predict_pcf HTTP/1.1')
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/1346

Comment: Also https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/1345 may well be relevant.